# How to use native views in React native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to build a react native app in which I would like to embed a native view, could anyone tell me how to do this using a detailed example, i checked the guides but couldn't really follow.

I am currently using a viewController class to display the view in the native iOS app, I would like to display the same view using my react native app. Do I need to use a UIView class or can I also use a view controller class? If yes, how can I do it?

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details of embedding native views are very clearly explained (including example MapView) in the react-native documentation: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content

Comment: thanks for the response, I have taken a look at this explanation but in this case I would need to render the View which is a subclass of the UIView. But I have implemented the entire view in the view controller. I don't know how to proceed now..

Comment: From what I understand, you can only embed views this way (because view is simply a - usually - rectangular "view" that you can easily embed. View Controller on the other hand is usually used to managed whole hierarchy of views - so when you want to show the whole screen rather than single component. It looks like (maybe?) you want to reverse it and use http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content - so have your react-native RCTView embedded as part of your overall application view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933743/6489702

In short; you load the `View` of the `UIViewController` as a subview to your native module but the `Controller` of the `UIViewController` you load as a child to the `KeyWindow` `UIViewController` that way you can use a native `UIViewController` but still have your native view live in the life cycle and size of the native view module.