# How can I present a native UIViewController in React Native? (Can't use just a UIView)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use ABNewPersonViewController in my React Native app. This is how it's used in Objective-C:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:NO completion:nil];
```

How would I do this in React Native? I can't write a bridged UI component since it's a UIViewController, not a UIView.

Please don't tell me to reimplement it

Answer (score 18):

Here's what ended up working for me.

CreateContact.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface CreateContact : NSObject <ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate, RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

CreateContact.m:

```
#import "CreateContact.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation CreateContact

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(CreateContact);


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(presentContact) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
        picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
        UINavigationController* contactNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:contactNavigator animated:NO completion:nil];
    });
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [newPersonViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

This tutorial has more detail: http://moduscreate.com/leverage-existing-ios-views-react-native-app/

I'll update as I implement the best way to communicate information back to RN.

Comment: Does exactly what it needs to! Thanks for the help.

Comment: #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h> is this storyboard ?? could you please explain this in detail

Answer (score 6):

You want to implement a bridged UI component that mounts an empty UIView and is responsible primarily for presenting your UIViewController. The simplest example of this technique is in RCTModalHostView; [check out the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/React/Views/RCTModalHostView.m#L89).

Notably, React Native defines a category on UIView that adds a property called `reactViewController` which climbs the view hierarchy to find the closest UIViewController. Use this UIViewController to present your custom view controller:

```c
- (void)didMoveToWindow
{
  [super didMoveToWindow];

  if (!_isPresented && self.window) {
    [self.reactViewController presentViewController:_customViewController
                                           animated:NO
                                         completion:nil];
    _isPresented = YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: So we have UIViews responsible for presenting UIViewControllers. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: MUCH more straightforward than the first answer. Thank you.

Comment: @PostCodeism It certainly does not seem right but RN's rigid interface forces us towards workarounds like this. Would be great if RN worked directly with a `UIViewController`.

Comment: It has been a while since the answer above, React Native has improved a lot...I'm wondering if is there a better way to do this nowadays...ty

Answer (score 1):

What you can actually do is have the UIViewController added as a child to the key window view controller but still have the view of the UIViewController added as a subview to the native module view so it's contained in the frame and lifecycle of the native module view without presenting the UIViewController itself outside the life of the native module view as so ->

```
UIWindow *window = (UIWindow*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window.rootViewController addChildViewController:_myViewController];
_myViewController.view.frame = self.superview.frame;
[self addSubview:_myViewController.view];
[_myViewController didMoveToParentViewController:window.rootViewController];
```

Here is the full implementation ->

In your MyViewManager.m add

```
#import "RCTUIManager.h"

@interface MyViewManager ()

@end

@implementation MyViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView*)view
{
    return [[MyView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

and in your MyView.h add

```
#if __has_include("React/RCTViewManager.h")
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
#else
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#endif

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView

@property(nonatomic, strong)UIViewController* myViewController;

@end
```

and in your MyView.m add

```
#import "MyView.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{

}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (_myViewController != nil) {
        _myViewController.view.frame = self.frame;
    }
}

- (void)removeFromSuperview {
    if (_myViewController != nil) {
         [_myViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
         [_myViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
         [_myViewController removeFromParentViewController];
         _myViewController = nil;
         [super removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(void)addViewControllerAsSubView
{
    _myViewController = [UIViewController new];
    UIWindow *window = (UIWindow*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window.rootViewController addChildViewController:_myViewController];
    _myViewController.view.frame = self.superview.frame;
    [self addSubview:_myViewController.view];
    [_myViewController didMoveToParentViewController:window.rootViewController];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Are there any open-source libs you can point me to that use this approach?

Comment: Hi @jspizziri, I use it in my library here https://github.com/chaimPaneth/react-native-jw-media-player/blob/master/ios/RNJWPlayer/RNJWPlayerView.m#L674

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to present an alert view controller by doing the following, perhaps it can be adapted to your use case!

Native module:

```
import type {TurboModule} from 'react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/RCTExport';
import {TurboModuleRegistry} from 'react-native';

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  displayView(): void;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.get<Spec>(
  'ViewPresenter',
) as Spec | null;
```

Objective-C definition:

```
#import "ViewPresenterSpec.h"
#import "ViewPresenter.h"

@implementation ViewPresenter

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (void)displayView {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    if (viewController.presentedViewController && !viewController.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed) {
        viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
    }
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                  message:@"This is an alert test."
                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
  });
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:
    (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
    return std::make_shared<facebook::react::NativeViewPresenterSpecJSI>(params);
}

@end
```

Comment: Interesting. So on the React side this would use `NativeModules.ViewPresenter` and not `requireNativeComponent('ViewPresenter')`?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below to render swift `UIControllerView` into my react native project.

- Recorder.m file

```
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RecorderManager, RCTViewManager)

@end
```

- RecorderManager.swift file

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(RecorderManager)
class RecorderManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return RecorderView().view
  }

  @objc(presentViewController)
  func presentViewController() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let viewController = RecorderView()
      let rootViewController = RCTPresentedViewController()

      rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

- RecorderView.swift file

```
import UIKit

@objcMembers
@objc(RecorderView)
class RecorderView: UIViewController {
  let nextButton = UIButton()
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    setupButton()
  }
  

  func setupButton() {
    view.addSubview(nextButton)
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
      nextButton.configuration = .filled()
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
      nextButton.configuration?.title = "It worked!"
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
  }
}
```