# How to create a React Native component using ARKit / a swift ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, arkit

We have a project based on the swift based `ARKit` example [Capturing Body Motion in 3D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) from the WWDC 2019. And we have a React Native app using native swift components, following the great instructions from [Swift in React Native - The Ultimate Guide](https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-2-ui-components-907767123d9e). Now we want to implement the view from the [ARKit example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) as a react-native component, but I just don't find out how to do this.

The [ARKit example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) uses a `UIViewController` with `ARSessionDelegate`, which means we have to wrap more than a simple view in the component.

I found some answers on [how to present a native UIViewController in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562274/how-can-i-present-a-native-uiviewcontroller-in-react-native-cant-use-just-a-u), but could not translate this solution into swift code and could not get it to work with the [ARKit example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d). Does anybody of you have an idea how to wire this up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I understand it by now ;-)

In the example [Capturing Body Motion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) in 3D all functionality is implemented in the `UIViewController`. We do not have separate `UIViewController` for each component in react native, we have `RCTViewManager` instead.

We can create our own View class, based on ARView and move the `ARSessionDelegate` from the `UIViewController` directly to this new view, including the `session` method and all corresponding parts.
An instance of this new View van be returned from the `RCTViewManager` and voila, it works!

Comment: Could you share code for this please?

Comment: At least present some code or repository.