# How to extend UIViewController for React Native iOS UI component?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to implement a custom `UIViewController` for my React Native "native iOS" UI component, as I need to override methods such as `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. How do I do this given the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-ios) make no mention of `UIViewController`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562274/how-can-i-present-a-native-uiviewcontroller-in-react-native-cant-use-just-a-u

For listening to native events, refer to this --- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8714#issuecomment-234437319

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I present a native UIViewController in React Native? (Can't use just a UIView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562274/how-can-i-present-a-native-uiviewcontroller-in-react-native-cant-use-just-a-u)